# Data not displaying in gmail attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to export gridview in pdf and attach as attachment 
 but data is not showing in pdf but columns and rows appearing in pdf is same as 
 my data.[This is the pdf I get as attachment in my gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSMgP.png) and the code for sending mail with attachment is given below

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
                using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    gvMisConduct.DataSource = Session["printdt"];
                    gvMisConduct.DataBind();
                    gvMisConduct.RenderControl(hw);
                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

                    iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
                    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                        pdfDoc.Open();
                        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                        pdfDoc.Close();


                        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        memoryStream.Close();


                        mMailMessage.Body = "Sir," + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                        mMailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                        // Set the format of the mail message body as HTML
                        mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "GridViewPDF.pdf"));
                       // mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        // Set the priority of the mail message to normal
                        mMailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;

                        // Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
                        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                        object MailSmtpServer = clsDBOperation.GetScalar("select value from Settings where Category='MailSmtpServer'");
                        if (MailSmtpServer == null)
                        {
                            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid MailSmtpServer";
                            return;
                        }
                        mSmtpClient.Host = MailSmtpServer.ToString();
                        mSmtpClient.Port = 25;
                        mSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                        System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailFromAddress.ToString(), PasswordDecode(MailPassword.ToString()));
                        mSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        mSmtpClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
                        // string[] to = txtTo.Text.Split(';');

                        object Email;

                        // Email = clsDBOperation.GetScalar("select (select Email from School_ParentMaster where School_ParentMaster.AccountID=Accounts.Parent) Email from Accounts where Accounts.ID='" + hdnAccountId.Value + "'");
                        Email = ToAddress;
                        if (Email != null)
                        {
                            // mMailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Email.ToString()));
                            mMailMessage.To.Add(ToAddress.ToString());
                            mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
                        }


                        // Send the mail message
                        // mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
                        lblMessage.Text = "Message has been sent";
                        // clearall();
                        //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Mail", "window.close();", true);



                        lblMessage.Text = "Send successfully";
                        clearAll();
                        //Response.Redirect("Behaviour.aspx?Class=" + dlClass.SelectedItem.Text + "&Division=" + dlDivision.SelectedItem.Text + "&Type=Save", false);
                    }
                }
            }
 }
```

How can I display content in pdf ?? Please help

Comment: Split your PDF generation and Mail operations into different methods. Test your PDF code separately, does it work?

Comment: Yes it works separately